# .net winforms application font trimmed when scaling to 125%

Tags: winforms, telerik, font-scaling

When i set windows font to 125% 
my .net winforms application font truncated and that i don't want, not sure if there is any application wide setting to re-scale/adjust

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03NSQ.png)

[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: Set `AutoScaleMode = Dpi` instead of `Font` then (and set the Font explicitly to the Controls that inherit the Font). Your app should be DpiAware.

Comment: not sure what do you mean set font explicitly, you suggesting me to set font of each control seperately?

Comment: Select all the Buttons, set the Font (the Font can of course be the same). One single operation. The same for other Controls that *don't behave*. The Font is a property shared by many Controls. You can select them all, if necessary, excluding from the selection  those that don't have a Font property (as the PictureBox). It might not be even necessary, but it might require direct editing of the Form.designer.cs file. Test the Form with the Dpi setting beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

In R2 2017 we introduced built-in HDPI support in the Progress® Telerik® UI for WinForms suite. This coincides with the HDPI improvements Microsoft is bringing with .NET 4.7 and the Windows 10 Creators Update. The best part is that you will get this support no matter which .NET framework you are targeting (currently supported from .NET 2.0 and up). The following help article demonstrates how to enable the DPI scaling in your application: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/telerik-presentation-framework/dpi-support

Please have a look at this KB article which will give you some tips and tricks regarding developing a DPI-aware application: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/knowledge-base/hdpi-tips-and-tricks

I hope this information helps.